# Is it safe to run these instructions as a root user?

Tags: linux, shell, security

I have CentOS and I want install `scala` by: [Installing `scala` on CentOS](http://decisionstats.com/2014/04/15/installing-scala-on-centos/).

I want to ask if it's safe installing this as root user?

The commands are:

```
wget http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.10.1.tgz
tar xvf scala-2.10.1.tgz
sudo mv scala-2.10.1 /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/scala-2.10.1 /usr/lib/scala
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/scala/bin
scala -version
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. From the instructions, it looks like it won't harm your PC, but we don't know what's inside the tar. However, the command set doesn't contain anything explicitly malicious.

So, from non-paranoid point of view: yeah, it should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

The server not using HTTPS would be a concern...

the comms channel between you and the server holding the tgz could be MiTMed and hence you could install software as root that is controlled by someone else.

Comment: Yet the only commands that he runs as root is `mv` and `ln` - I'd call it safe.

Comment: Agreed re moving the software but I am arguing the software itself may not be benign and hence when it runs...

Comment: He runs the software as a normal user.